# Outlook for Mac (2016) using tons of disk space for Calendar Attachments

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

Keep getting notifications that I am running out of disk space. Delete several GB of files, then a few hours later get the notifications again. I traced the problem down to an Outlook folder called "Calendar Attachments".

```
~/Library/Group Containers/UB???????.Office/Outlook 15 Profiles/Outlook/Outlook 15 Profiles/Main Profile/Data/Calendar Attachments
```

Looking by size inside one of the subfolders, it appears the same attachment is being replicated over and over. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to remove the account from exchange.

- just terminate outlook process (rightclick quit)
- rename the directory
- create a new one with same name (Calendar Attachments)
- start outlook
- if everything is ok, delete previous directory.

i did it already twice - first time removed 230GB of garbage, second time 80GB, after another 2 days (hardly using outlook) the directory is at 20gb again...
it is a leak for sure.

Comment: When i did this, the leak continued to gobble up disk space. removing the Exchange account in Outlook and readding it seemed necessary, in my case anyway.

Answer (score -1):

The easy way to fix this is:

- delete the outlook account w/ exchange server
- quit outlook
- rename the folder mentioned above
- restart outlook
- re-add the account

Note that Calendar Attachments folder is used for both Exchange based calendar items, as well as locally stored items which you may have archived.